# Video hides when logo div is removed

Tags: html, css, video, browser

Hello fellow stackers.

I've got a slight problem. I'm trying to duplicated my webpage for another page, however whenever I try and remove the logo the video disappears. Not to sure why. I've input the code however I don't think its much use because it works find by itself, which leads me to believe that there is something within my code which relies on the logo being there. Your help is much obliged. The live example is [here](http://kadeem.london). If you inspect element on any browser and remove the logo you'll find that it disappears.

```css
 .Intro-Video {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 9999;
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     background-color: #fff;
     overflow: hidden;
 }

 .Intro-Video1 {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 9999;
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     margin-top: 200px;
     background-color: #fff;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 .video-box {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
 }
 #video-container {
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 video {
     position:absolute;
     z-index:0;
 }
 video.fillWidth {
     width: 100%;
 }

.Kadeem-Logo {
     position: relative;
     top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     display:block;
 }
 .Kadeem-Logo img {
     display: block;
     width: auto;
     max-width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
                <div class="video-box">
                    <div id="video-container">
                        <video autoplay class="fillWidth">
                            <source src="http://client.hugoandmarie.com.s35719.gridserver.com/client/AlexandraPosen/Alex_Posen_Video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                        </video>
                        
                         <div class="Kadeem-Logo">
                             <img src="http://www.kadeem.london/Content/Image/KL.png" alt="Kadeem Logo" title="Kadeem Logo">
                         </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n4xshhdv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logo image is providing all the height for the container.

Try this:

```
#video-container {
  height: 550px; /* Or whatever height you want */
}
```

To fix the issue.

Comment: Should I use media queries to keep the container responsive?

Comment: There are a wealth of possibilities on how to keep it responsive.  Were I in your shoes, I'd recommend figuring out how much of the initial screen you want shown, and then size your video like so: `#video_container { height: 50vh; width: 100vw; }`.  The `vh` is the percent of the available view port you'd like to size the element.  The same is true for `vw` but based on the available view port width.